# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while running a NSOpenPanel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS while running a NSOpenPanel to select a directory on the file system.

The app crashes only if I create a new folder (with the default "New Folder" button) and then I select it and open it (with the default "Open" button.

If I just open an existing folder everything works.

```
NSOpenPanel *browsePanel = [[NSOpenPanel alloc] init];
    [browsePanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
    [browsePanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [browsePanel setCanCreateDirectories:YES];
    [browsePanel beginSheetForDirectory:nil
                                   file:nil
                                  types:nil
                         modalForWindow:self.window
                          modalDelegate:self
                         didEndSelector:@selector(browsePanelPanelDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                            contextInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[sender tag]]];
```

The app crashes before the didEndSelector is invoked.

thanks

ps. I've tried to set contextInfo to nil, and it crashes anyway.

Comment: What does your "browsePanelPanelDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:" method look like? And what is the stack trace?

Comment: is browsePanelPanelDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:getting invoked?

Comment: @Mark F I wrote in the question that browsePanelPanelDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo: is not invoked before the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis normally happens because you are sending a message to a deallocated object. Also known as a Zombie. There are two things you can do, first run the app with NSZombieEnabled=YES, or secondly run instruments and hunt for zombies. I would recommend using instruments as it gives the best feedback and allows you to explore the data.

Enabling Zombie detection will show you which object is being sent the message and allow you to hunt down either why you are sending the message or why you are deallocating something you want.

You code above is not enough detail to figure this out. It's not unusual for the Zombie to be in a completely different section of code because it's all about deallocated instances. Something you may have done elsewhere.